# Java/OAF Date Conversion Error through Callable Statement

Tags: java, sql-server, date

I am passing date in OAF page to SQL database through Callable statement. I looked at many solution but still I'am getting no Success. This is What I've written.

```
OAMessageDateFieldBean validFrom =(OAMessageDateFieldBean)webBean.findIndexedChildRecursive("VaidFrom");

String getValidFrom = validFrom.getValue(pageContext).toString();

SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("DD/MM/YYYY");
System.out.println("Formatter Executed " + formatter);

Date dateValidFrom ;
dateValidFrom = null;
java.sql.Date sqlDate = null;

        try {
                System.out.println("Formatter Date Valid from "+formatter.parse(getValidFrom));
                dateValidFrom = (java.sql.Date)formatter.parse(getValidFrom);
                sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(dateValidFrom.getTime());
                System.out.println("SQL date is "+sqlDate);

                }catch (Exception e){
                    System.out.println("------ "+e);
               } 

callableStatement.setDate(3, sqlDate);
```

I tried to debug it and I think error is coming in  **dateValidFrom = (java.sql.Date)formatter.parse(getValidFrom);**

The error it is showing is - **java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Date cannot be cast to java.sql.Date**

I've used Date Picker to pick date into the field. The value that is stored in String is

```
2017-05-01 00:00:00.0
```

And the value coming after SimpleDateFormat is used is -

```
Mon Dec 05 00:01:00 IST 2016
```

Please help.
TIA

Comment: Try `java.sql.Date.valueOf` instead of type casting.

Comment: `DD/MM/YYYY` as format pattern? Capital D is day in year (not day in month), M is month alright, and Y is week year, occassionally not the same as calendar year. Didn’t you mean `dd/MM/yyyy`?

Answer (score 0):

Don't cast dateValidFrom in java.sql.Date beacause formatter.parse return a java.util.Date

Try something like that  :

```
java.util.Date dateValidFrom = formatter.parse(getValidFrom);
java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(dateValidFrom.getTime());
```

Comment: I tried your method but it is giving me **'Illegal pattern character 'Y' '** exception.

Comment: Here's the documentation for date pattern : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html